# insert into datagridview to sql dynamic column name using SQL Parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, datagridview, parameters

Is there a way to prevent sql from crashing using the answer in the link below 
[Insert from datagridview to SQL with dynamic column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449146/insert-from-datagridview-to-sql-with-dynamic-column-names)

wanted to prevent sql injection as per link 
[SqlCommand Parameters vs. String.Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153217/sqlcommand-parameters-vs-string-format)

Comment: Define "crashing"? What are you seeing? What code are you using? What is your scenario?

Comment: i am using the 1st link code error is as follows System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'ENTREPRISES'.